# Python choose filepath UI

Tags: python, interface

I already know how to add a filepath selection to my N-Panel UI thanks to this:
[Python Panel Dropdownlist and Integer Button](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170219/python-panel-dropdownlist-and-integer-button)
But how do I access the selected path?
I would love to print out the selected path.

Comment: ... the example above prints the path to the console and shows how to access the value (the actual path) of your property. Further reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the lines:

```
col.prop(placeholder, "inc_dec_int", text="Increment/Decrease")
        col.prop(placeholder, "dropdown_box", text="Dropdown")
        col.prop(placeholder, "file_path", text="Filepath")
```

Add:

```
print(placeholder["file_path"])
```

To print the selected file-path of the file-browser.